# Which signal is related to leaving a widget?

Tags: python, widget, pyqt, signals-slots, qlineedit

I code `PyQt`, I have the following code:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.checkBox, \
QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked(bool)")), lambda: \
self.interfaceCodesConstructor.setFilterList(self,"name",self.lineEdit.text()))
```

Abobe code causes When i click on checkbox, my function : `setFilterList`
will be run.

i need to run above function:
`setFilterList(self,"name",self.lineEdit.text())` When i leave a
`LineEdit widge`, But i don't know its `signal`.

**My question** is : What's its `signal` when you *leave* a `widget` such as
`LineEdit`?

Yours,
Mohsen

Comment: https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#signals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#signals) `QlineEdit` will emit 
`void QLineEdit::editingFinished () [signal]` when the line edit widget loses focus.